Error Retrieving Acronym List from Search Endpoint
I'm trying to retrieve all the acronyms in the M365 Search database, using this endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/acronyms (per this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-searchentity-list-acronyms?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). This was previously working but all of a sudden has stopped, both in code and via Graph Explorer. The app has the right permissions (it was working!) and so does my user in Graph. I'm testing across tenants as well. Has something changed with this endpoint?

Same for me. It doesn't work. I've tried SearchConfiguration.Read.All and Acronym.Read.All, but it returns 403.

With these permissions- SearchConfiguration.Read.All, SearchConfiguration.ReadWrite.All it should work. Have you retried just incase it was a transient error. If not please share the corelation ID and timestamp

It's back working again - we logged a support ticket and apparently there was an issue in our Azure zone.

Great to hear it is working!
